# Looking for a specific book containing a collection of sci-fi stories and articles, one of which was about space cables

Tags: story-identification, technology, anthology-book

I have a vague recollection of reading about space cables in a chapter near the end of book which was a collection of stories. I think that this was at least 20 years ago.

"Space cables" are magnetically levitated mass streams that travel inside an evacuated sheath. They are a basic building block of inertially supported active structures, such as Partial Orbital Ring Systems, Lofstrom Loops, and Tethered Rings.

I used to read a lot of Larry Niven in those days, but I haven't been able to rediscover this chapter in any of his books. So, the book might have been written by a different author.

(BTW, I'm pretty sure that it is *not* Robert L. Forward's "Indistinguishable From Magic")

Comment: There's a fictionalized description of a space cable in [*Amazing Stories*, June 1982](https://archive.org/details/Amazing_Stories_v56n01_1982-06/page/n21/mode/2up?q=%22space+cable%22) by J. Ray Dettling called "[Tomorrow's Amazing Transport Machines](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?118601)" but it's never been collected anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks - really interesting read! However, the "space cable" in this story is a space elevator cable, not the mass stream kind that I remember reading about. The search continues. BTW, what did you mean by "it's never been collected anywhere else"?

Comment: @phil1008 David means the story has not been published in an anthology, so you could not have read it unless you read the Amazing Stories issue it appeared in.

Comment: Or, of course, the database doesn't have an entry for the anthology. I know that I've submitted a few entries to the ISFDB.

Comment: @DavidW I think what I'm asking is "Can you tell us how exhaustive your search technique was?" For example, if you were somehow able to do a search through the text of all books ever published, that would imply that I got some some of the details wrong, like perhaps I misremembered the term "space cable".

Comment: @phil1008 Nowhere near that exhaustive.  Up to the late 1980s or so most short fiction that was anthologized had previously been published in one of the science fiction magazines; up to around 2000 it was still probably the majority.  So I text searched the [Pulp Magazine Archive](https://archive.org/details/pulpmagazinearchive) which has most non-*Analog* magazines, plus my own archive of *Analog*; the noted result was the only reasonably close one I found.  (Apparently in the 1950s some astronauts still received "space cables" by space telegraph or something.)

Comment: I also searched the general collection of the Internet Archive, and Google books in `subject:"Science Fiction"` with no other useful hits.  (e.g. KSR uses the term "space cable" once in *Blue Mars*, but it's referring to the physical structure of the beanstalk.)

Comment: Thanks for doing such a thorough search!

Comment: Could it be "Borderlands of Science" by Charles Sheffield? I don't think that had any SF stories in it though.

Comment: Looks like an interesting and relevant book! I'm going to read it some more to be sure, but after giving it a quick scan I don't think it's the one I read before.

Comment: Did the book specifically mention _Lofstrom Loops_ or was that just an example of what the cables could be used for? I remember Fred Pohl uses Lofstrom Loops as plot devices in several of his books, though I don't remember him describing the sort of cables you mention.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about that but I feel like it did not. It seemed to have an excited tone - like the author had just thought of (or heard of) the idea, as opposed to the tone of someone who was reporting on Keith Lofstrom's work. I do also recall that it was suggested that a possible application for space cables was larger-than-normal bridges.